# Where to find list of full name (NOT abbreviations!) of stock exchanges where particular enterprises has their stocks in?

Tags: stocks, stock-markets, stock-analysis, stock-exchanges, stock-valuation

Would anyone be able to help with the question in title? So far I only know Bloomberg and their ''Stocks'' menu and it's corresponding fields to search the public enterprises with publicly traded stocks. However, the problem is that it often happens that I don't recognizes abbreviation of reported stock exchange and I would need a full name. I tried MarketWatch website too but they don't have the data of ALL, I repeat **ALL**, worldwide ( ! ) public enterprises, including the ones that just moved from being private to being public, and full name of stock exchanges where they have their stocks in, all of the stock exchanges. Where could I find, e.g. for X company, full list of stock exchanges they have their stocks accounts in (brokerage accounts)? I saw information on Investing dot Com website but not even there is full name of stock exchange which is really important for me to be available. Besides that, the data on Bloomberg and Investing doesn't even match.

Comment: You could Google the abbreviations.

Comment: It's a good question but surprisingly, the answer is "there is no such thing".  Sorry!

Comment: You can run {EXC} and {EIS} on BBG to get a full list of the stock exchanges including the abbreviation, full name and what permissions you have (real-time access etc.)

Answer (score 2):

There is no centralized place for a registry like you ask for.

Companies don't necessarily know or care where their stock is traded - so they will not have a list. It's like asking 'all places where Toyotas are traded' - Toyota wouldn't know nor care, neither would anybody else.

Comment: Toyota certainly knows all the *new car* dealerships.

Answer (score 0):

The [FT stock screener](https://markets.ft.com/data/equities) has more international coverage than many American sites.